# Enum with constexpr std::string_view vs instantiated enum with std::string

Tags: c++, enums, static, constexpr

I would like to have `struct`s holding `enum`s for iteration, together with `std::string` holding their names for creating menu entries. I was using something like this:

```
struct S
{
    enum E { ONE, TWO, ALL };
    std::array<std::string, ALL> names { "one", "two" };
};
int main()
{
    S s;
    for(int i=s.ONE; i<s.ALL; ++i) // or S::...
        std::cout << s.names[i] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand, this is preferred to having global variables. It works, but needs instantiation before usage. Now, I found out about this method, which needs `--std=C++17` to compile:

```
struct S
{
    enum E { ONE, TWO, ALL };
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, ALL> names { "one, "two" };
};
int main()
{
    for(int i=S::ONE; i<S::ALL, ++i)
        std::cout << S::names[i] << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

But how will this behave, in terms of memory usage, compared to my previous way of doing this? Or is there a wrong way in how I do it? What would be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that `enum` when using `std::array`. You can do this:

```
struct S
{
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, 2> names { "one", "two" };
};

int main()
{
    for(auto name: S::names)
        std::cout << name << '\n';
}
```

Or this:

```
int main()
{
    for(auto n = std::begin(S::names); n != std::end(S::names); ++n)
        std::cout << *n << '\n';
}
```

This is very different from your first example though because now you only have *one* array for ***every*** `sruct S`. Before, every struct has its own copy of the array.

So do what suits your need. One array per object? Or one array for **all** your objects?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not always that I need all the entries, some may be skipped, so I don't always use the `for()` loop, or sometimes it's limited `for(int i=S::THREE; i<S::SEVEN; ++i)`.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You can do: `for(auto i = std::begin(S::names) + 2; i < std::begin(S::names) + 6; ++i) {}`

Comment: Of course I would rather minimize the memory usage, but it may not be as readable, that's why the `enum`. Still, despite using `std::begin` and `std::end`, you seem to use a `struct`, as well, you just drop the `enum`. If I use `enum` and then, as you suggest, `for(auto i=std::begin(S::names)+S::TWO; ...)`, would that be as effective as only having one array in memory, no matter how many `for()` loops are calling it?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen To be honest I am not sure that `std::begin(S::names) + S::TWO` is any clearer than `std::begin(S::names) + 2`. But its up to you.

Comment: I might also have some doubts, but it's more along the lines of `S::LEGENDRE`. Still, this seems a good way to minimize having too many objestc (which I was trying to avoid with thi snew method, rather than instantiating an object for each case).

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what you ask, but except from a few small errors in your example it's fine.

If we change the example a bit to not use iostream (because it's confusing with that much code in the assembly listing). An example, instead summing the size of the names:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <array>

struct S
{
    enum E { ONE, TWO, ALL };
    static constexpr std::array<std::string_view, ALL> names { "one", "two" };
};
int main()
{
    int l=0;
    for(int i=S::ONE; i<S::ALL; ++i){
        l+= S::names[i].size() ;                 
    }

return l;
}
```

It compiles to a few assembly instructions representing "return 6". But, as Galik points out, no need for the enum trick.

https://godbolt.org/g/ot2kpt

You can also pick a range to loop over, like this:

```
for(auto n = std::begin(S::names)+1; n != std::end(S::names); ++n)
```

Comment: Sorry about the errors, I just typed it from memory.