# Using static const string[] as a member instead of a global, initialized in the .cpp file

Tags: c++, arrays, string, static, constants

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49598101/enum-with-constexpr-stdstring-view-vs-instantiated-enum-with-stdstring). I'd like to avoid using global variables so I resorted to using `struct`s with `enum` and `std::string[]` (see link) in order to build menus for a small application. I would also like to have these `enum`s in a separate header file. The selected answer in the link implies using `--std=c++17`, which I'd like to avoid, at least for now, and decided to use a `static const std::string[]` -- no need to include extra `array` or `vector` since this is initialized once, never modified, only called, `ALL` is always known.

As other answers on this have made it clear, I need to either initialize `A::names` outside the `struct`, or use a `static const std::string&` setter (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983511/how-can-you-define-const-static-stdstring-in-header-file), for example). But all the answers so far dealt with a `std::string`, not an array, `std::string[]`.

This is a simple example of what I tried. It simply tries to print the contents of `A::names` using a `for()` loop iterating through the `enum` in `struct A`:

a.h:

```
#ifndef A_H_INCLUDED
#define A_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

struct A
{
    enum E { ONE, TWO, ALL };
    static const std::string names[ALL];
};
#endif // A_H_INCLUDED
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"

static const std::string A::names[A::ALL] { "one", "two" };
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i=A::ONE; i<A::ALL; ++i)
        std::cout << A::names[i] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The error after `g++ main.cpp` is:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `A::names[abi:cxx11]'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Seeing the `cxx11`, I thought `g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp` would solve it, but it doesn't.

So, what am I doing wrong, or, how could I adapt the version with the setter to return an array, `std::string[]`? My goal is to have an alternative to a global variable, that has only one instance in memory no matter how many calls.

---

Here's an adapted code, from a small program, on how I would build a menu using `struct` with `enum` and `string` (`menu_design = new QMenu...` and `menuDesignAction()` is the function that updates):

```
for(unsigned char i=0; i<A::ALL; ++i)    // needs initializing
{
    QAction *tmpAction {new QAction(tr(A::names[i].c_str()))};
    tmpAction->setObjectName(QString("%1").arg(i));
    connect(tmpAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(menuDesignAction()));
    menu_design->addAction(tmpAction);
}
```

As a side-note, in the snippet above, I have to use `.c_str()`, but I am using a `std::string` in the `enum`. If I could make it `*char[]` instead of `std::string[]`, would I avoid extra calls? If I am not wrong, how could the answers to my problem (assuming there are) be adapted so as to be able to fit somehow in the Qt snippet?

Comment: You don't seem to build with `a.cpp`?

Comment: Oh god, I feel stupid! You're right, I forgot to add it! It works, but will this only have one instance in memory, no matter how many calls?

Comment: That's one of the points of `static` member variables, that there will be only one instance of them.

Comment: Thank you! If you make this an answer, I'll select it. It solved my (very beginner) problem.

Comment: In a.cpp, remove the qualifier `static`.  Gcc might allow it, but other compilers won't. Leave it in a.h.

Comment: @JiveDadson You're right, I was just typing from memory and forgot I shouldn't add it there. It isn't in my files.